# Messy toolbox text in Libre office 5.1.6.2?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I have a problem with LibreOffice interface the texts in the tool boxes seem to be interfering with each other like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use another (system level/menu) font - or try an upgrade of your LO version.